# Javascript image onload method - catching errors

Tags: javascript

This (`getSizeFromObjectUrl`) function works well to calculate height and width for actual images. I tried this with files (objectURLs) other than images (ex: text files), the code never reaches to catch block in try-catch. What are ways for catching errors/load-exceptions with `img.onload`?

```
function getSizeFromObjectUrl(dataURL: string): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        try {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const ratio = Math.min(maxImageWidth / img.width, maxImageHeight / img.height, 1);
                resolve({
                    width: img.width * ratio,
                    height: img.height * ratio
                });
            };
            img.src = dataURL;
        } catch (exception) {
            logCalculateImageSizeFailed(exception);
            // handle error
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promise reject for `img.onerror`

note, added `reject` argument to Promise executor callback - see comments in code

```
function getSizeFromObjectUrl(dataURL: string): Promise<{width: number;height: number}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // amended this line
        const img = new Image();
        img.onerror = reject; // added this line
        img.onload = () => {
            const ratio = Math.min(maxImageWidth / img.width, maxImageHeight / img.height, 1);
            if (img.width && img.height) {
                resolve({
                    width: img.width * ratio,
                    height: img.height * ratio
                });
            } else {
                reject('Bad Image');
            }
        };
        img.src = dataURL;
    }).catch(exception => {
        logCalculateImageSizeFailed(exception);
        // handle error
    });
}
```

Comment: Do we know the cause of error? Like any thrown error/exception?

Comment: If you bothered to run the code, you'll see the error in `catch` @Prakhar

Comment: This doesn't work, error is not getting caught in catch block.

Comment: I assumed too much about your original code - didn't notice the try/catch inside the Promise executor - I've rewritten the code, should work now - there's also a check to see if the image has a width and height

Comment: I don't think it ever goes inside image.onload when it is not an image. The else rejection seems never executed. Neither goes to catch while onload by other means.

Comment: something like this would work - img.onerror = (error) => { console.log(`error: ${error}`); };

Comment: Oh well ... I can't see why you can't get it working, works fine for me @Prakhar

Comment: your `img.onerror` *"solution"* would result in the promise never settling (neither resolved nor rejected) on error - I highly doubt that's your intention - but if it is, go for it @Prakhar